# How can I use configuration(macro) values in .rc files (vs2010 ro vs2013)?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, rc

I want to use some configuration(macro) variables, e.g. $(Configuration) in my .rc file. For example I want to have something like this in my .rc file.

```
....
....
VALUE "InternalName", "MyProjectName $(Configuration)"
....
....
```

But, the result, when I see my projects output's properties, is <> rather than <> as I expected!

Is it possible?
Note: I need to have different values in different configurations. For example I want to have different application name (that will come in my application properties) in Debug and Release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define *a macro* at Resource compiler commandline.

> Project properties -> Resources -> General -> "Preprocessor Defines"

```
CONFIGURATION=$(Configuration);
```

Use in *RC* and remember to *stringize* if used as string.

```
#define _STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) _STRINGIZE(x)

VALUE "InternalName", "MyProjectName " STRINGIZE(CONFIGURATION)
```